# How to install preprocessor using pip

Tags: python

I am trying to install preprocessor using pip and i am getting the following error:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

I am not sure whats the problem here.

Comment: please prepare your input and output properly

Comment: Are you talking about this package? https://pypi.org/project/preprocessor/ Can you share the exact command you're using to try and install it? And a full copy of the error message, if there's anything beyond what you already shared?

Comment: share your input command and error page.

Answer (score 1):

better try this `pip install tweet-preprocessor` or

```
pip install preprocess
```